# Scoping issues in Javascript in Laravel blade file

Tags: javascript, laravel, scoping

Working on an app whereby am fetching some data from the backend and populating dynamically on a Laravel blade file.
Am using Javascript to do the task, On the frontend I have partitioned in 2 major columns (left column and right column). On the left column there is a link which when hovered over or clicked the respective policies display on the right side.

On Javascript code have created a functionality whereby when the document is ready fetch all the data and add in a variable called asmData. Next on mouse enter event (on a link on left side of the page) display respective policies on the table.

The problem is am getting error of asmData when I use the code below(alternative 1) and wehn I pass all the data of mouse enter event inside document.ready function (alternative 2) I dont see any data on the table.

**Left column containing the link with a dynamic id**

```
 <div class="col-md-4">
    @foreach($asm as $a)
         <a href="#demo{{$i}}" class="list-group-item list-group-item-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#MainMenu" style="color: #868ba1;" id="{{ $a['id'] }}"> Agency Sales ID : {{ $a['id'] }} </a>
    @endforeach
    </div>
```

**Right column containing the table I would like to populate dynamically**

```
 <div class="col-md-8">
     <table class="table table-hover mg-b-0 tx-11" id="summary-table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>POLICY NUMBER</th>
            <th>NAME</th>
            <th>STATUS</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr> <!-- Add policies dynamically via JS under respective thead columns--></tr> 
          </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
```

**JavaScript code (Alternative 1)**

```
//Check if asm variable is set
<?php if(isset($asm) and isset($usm) and isset($ag)){ ?>
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var asmData = {!! json_encode($asm) !!};
});

$(document).on("mouseenter", "a", function() {

   var $tb = $('#summary-table tbody');

       //Make sure table is empty
       $tb.empty();

  //Fetch id of a tag in the DOM
  var asmId = $(this).attr('id');
  var asmPolicies = '';
  for(var i = 0; i < asmData.length; i++) {
      if(asmId == asmData[i]['id']) {
          for(var j = 0; j < asmData[i]['policies'].length; j++){
              var pol = asmData[i]['policies'][j];
              asmPolicies += '<tr><td>' + pol.policy_no + '</td><td>' + pol.policy_holder_name + '</td><td>' + pol.status + '</td><td>' + '</td></tr>';
          }
      }
  }
  // we append asmPolicies Html to the table
  $tb.append(asmPolicies);
  //END ASM
});
<?php } ?>
```

**JavaScript code (Alternative 2 )**

```
//Check if asm variable is set
<?php if(isset($asm) and isset($usm) and isset($ag)){ ?>

//document is ready
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var asmData = {!! json_encode($asm) !!};

   //On mouse enter
  $(document).on("mouseenter", "a", function() {

   var $tb = $('#summary-table tbody');

       //Make sure table is empty
       $tb.empty();

  //Fetch id of a tag in the DOM
  var asmId = $(this).attr('id');
  var asmPolicies = '';
  for(var i = 0; i < asmData.length; i++) {
      if(asmId == asmData[i]['id']) {
          for(var j = 0; j < asmData[i]['policies'].length; j++){
              var pol = asmData[i]['policies'][j];
              asmPolicies += '<tr><td>' + pol.policy_no + '</td><td>' + pol.policy_holder_name + '</td><td>' + pol.status + '</td><td>' + '</td></tr>';
          }
      }
  }
  // we append asmPolicies Html to the table
  $tb.append(asmPolicies);
  //END ASM
});
});
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: What is the error you getting?

Comment: Thanks alot,, I solved the bug

Comment: Just as a hint, you say your are using the Laravel Blade template engine but you aren't actually using it. You have used raw PHP but the blade @if would make it cleaner. Also, if there a reason why you aren't using Blade to populate the content if there data is being passed from the controller?

Comment: @Petay87  I solved the issue..